# Strange path expected while Exporting Android project from Eclipse to Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, export

[image]

Hi All,

I am trying to export an Eclipse android project  for  Studio.
There are 2 libraries

- Facebook
- Main(Twitter)
  And the main Project
- JabongShareApp
  When i try to export selecting all 3, the browser says the following : See below image.

Cant really figure out why  this path , I even tried creating this path and putting Facebook library there, No success.

Can someone point out my mistake?

Comment: maybe you can try to directly import project in android.

Comment: Well that's a pain, making all those gradle files :(

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

[image]

As I know , Android studio can import eclipse project without gralde files.